# What does 且 mean by itself?

Tags: translation

I was watching Blur's new music video, which includes a recipe for ice cream with instructions in Chinese.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp1ks7PTzng)  At 3:03, the recipe says '将奶黄放入一个大，浅且可置于冷冻库的容器'.  I don't really understand how to translate this part.

Also, how would you translate ‘即可离火'?  This is in the recipe at 2:59.  Does it mean something like 'immediately take away from the heat?'

Many thanks.

Comment: I believe it means "and".

Comment: it means and, also (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4):

将奶黄放入一个大，浅且可置于冷冻库的容器 means 'put the custard into a huge, shallow container (and) which can be put into a freezer'.

So here 且 means `and`(而且).

Another useage 且 means 'just', such as 且行且珍惜(just cherish what you have at the moment) here 且 means just.

即可(离火) means you can do something when something happen as soon as possbile.

Such as: 
1. 当油热了，即可离火 (When the oil is hot, you can turn off fire right now[She suggest you do it right now]).
2. 开袋即食 (Open the bag, you can eat it)

即 has a meaning of you can do something with a hint do it now(as soon as possible).

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't help that the comma is wrong.  It should be:

...大、浅且可以...的容器

Place it in a large, shallow *and* (且) able to be...container.

Comment: Here it is short for [而且](http://www.zdic.net/c/c/29/63105.htm), which means "and".

Comment: 而且 is just a combination of two classical particles each of which mean different things - "while" (as a transition eg "..., while I think that...")+"and". Not disagreeing,just pointing out the utility of breaking things down as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, `且` means `and`. There are many good answers above.

For your second question, `即可离火`, it means `as long as .... you can take it away from heat`. `即` indicates when some condition reaches, you should/can do something. It may vary in different situations. I just watched the Youtube video and I think it means "as long as you can scratch a clear path on the surface of the custard, you should take it away from the heat".

Comment: might be slightly more accurate to say "as soon as...then you can take it away from the heat". "as long as" implies that you can then do whatever at anytime after the condition is met, which is not what I understand 即 to imply here.  Minor quibble.

Answer (score 1):

1. Here 且 = "and".
2. Here 即 means "就" as an adverb. "即可离火" means "Then (即) okay （可) to take away from heat."

Answer (score 0):

```
1. 既高且大。尚且。况且。moreover
2. 苟且偷安。姑且。for the time being, for now
3. 城且拔矣。年且九十。 about to, will soon (pre-verb)
4. 且走且说。also (post-subject)
5. 这双鞋且穿呢！long last,durable
6. 且说。mostly used in Chinese literature
7. 姓。a surname
```